# Get yesterday time PHP

Tags: php

I would like to have yesterday date:

```
        $from = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00");
        $to = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59");
```

Comment: The [date](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function has 2 parameters. the second one is the timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example 0:00:00 is the very first minute of TODAY. This is why it does not work.

You can use strtotime to fetch yesterday and then format the date as you want:

```
$from = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", strtotime("yesterday"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$today = strtotime('now');
$yesterday = strtotime('-1 day', $today);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("yesterday"));
```

Can't beat that for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in so many ways, a few examples:

```
$yesterday = time() - 3600 * 24; // obvious maybe, 3600 seconds in one hour: 60 * 60
$yesterday = strtotime('yesterday');
$yesterday = strtotime('-1 day', time());
```

It's whatever you think suits best...

the `$yesterday` timestamp can easily be converted to a readable string representation using [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). i.e:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', $yesterday);
```